# Intercept each request with before and after hooks

Tags: ajax, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have to make 5 requests (order doesn't matter) to 5 different endpoints. The URL of these endpoints is the same, except for the business line. These business lines are the array of the `from`.

I want show a skeleton loader before each request and hide once it finish. So, basically the flow is:

```
1. [Hook - before request]
2. [Log of data fetched]
3. [Hook - after request]
```

This is my service:

```
export function getInsurances(
    userIdentity: string,
    hooks?: RequestHooks
): Observable<Policy[]> {
    return from(["all", "vehicle", "health", "soat", "plans"]).pipe(
        tap(() => hooks?.beforeRequest && hooks.beforeRequest()),
        flatMap<string, Observable<Policy[]>>(businessLine => {
            return InsurancesApi.getPolicies<Policy>(
                userIdentity,
                businessLine
            ).pipe(
                map(policies => {
                    return policies.map(policy => PolicyStandarizer(policy));
                }),
                finalize(() => {
                    hooks?.afterRequest && hooks.afterRequest();
                })
            );
        }),
        catchError(err => of(err)),
        takeUntil(HttpCancelator)
    );
}
```

This is my subscribe:

```
const hooks = {
    beforeRequest() {
        Log.info("Before Request");
        setStatus(HttpRequestStatus.PENDING);
    },
    afterRequest() {
        Log.warn("After Request");
        setStatus(HttpRequestStatus.RESOLVED);
    },
};
getInsurances(userIdentity, hooks).subscribe(
    policies => {
        Log.normal("Policies:", policies);
        setInsurances(policies);
    },
    (err: Error) => {
        setError(err);
    }
);
```

And have this output (sorry for paste the link, I can't embed the image because rep):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbq49.png

The `finalize` is working fine, but the `tap` is executing five times at once.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get this behavior because `from` emits the items synchronously, so its essentially the same as doing:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log('before req');

  observer.next(arr[i]);
}

observer.complete();
```

`afterRequest` is shown properly because the actions involved are asynchronous.

If you want to trigger that event only once, before all the requests are fired, you could try this:

```js
from([...])
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => hooks?.beforeRequest && hooks.beforeRequest()),
    flatMap(/* ... */)
  )
```

#### EDIT - log event before each request

```js
flatMap(
  value => concat(
    of(null).pipe(
      tap(() => hooks?.beforeRequest && hooks.beforeRequest()),
      ignoreElements(), // Not interested in this observable's values
    ),
    InsurancesApi.getPolicies(/* ... */)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. I understand now why that behaviour. So, I won't to log "beforeRequest" once, I wanna log it before each request. Executing your code, it shows "beforeRequest" once.

Comment: Hmm, I see. But I'm pretty sure you'd end up with the same behavior from the beginning, because you'd subscribe to the inner observables synchronously. I don't see the point in logging that event for each one of them, knowing that their inner observables would be created synchronously.

Comment: How could I deal with it to achieve my purpose?